# Grabbing a word from a certain index value

Tags: javascript

Say for example I had the string "hello world" as a input string,

```
var str = document.getElementById("call_search").value;

function find_word() {
//code here?
}
```

and I wanted to get a word from a certain index, for example
I want the word from index 5 which would be "world".

How would I go about this?

Comment: When you say "the word from index 5", do you mean all the characters from index 5 up to the end of the string, or from the index to the first space or punctuation character, or...? What if the specified index isn't actually the start of a word? (In fact for "hello world" index 5 is a space - note that JS string index values start at 0, not 1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = 'Hello World';

str.slice(5); // " World"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

> str.slice(beginSlice[, endSlice])

Comment: WHat will happen if the string is Hello World !!!, the result in this case would be " World !!!", not " World". This is not the right answer, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

use `indexOf` and `slice` methods  to achive this

```
 //you can give the string and the  word that you want as a parameter to your find word function 
    function find_word(str,word) {

      var index=str.indexOf(word); 

     return str.slice(index);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of the OP's requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the next white space from the search Index. Slice the string from the search index to white space index to the word.

```
var str = 'Hello World Everyone';
var searchIndex = 5;
var endOfWord = str.indexOf(" ",searchIndex+1);
var output;
if(endOfWord === -1)
{
    endOfWord = str.length;
}
output = str.slice(searchIndex, endOfWord).trim();
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This solution has the same issue as mine. It chops of the word if the index happens to be at the middle of the word.